# arduino+Esp8266 + apk (TCP server-client)

Tags: arduino, esp8266

someone know how i can do a correct comunication with esp8266 and apk (tcp server<->tcp client)

Here is the problem:
[image]

I send values and esp8266 dont read it well sometime;

arduino bauidio:115200
esp8266 baudio:115200

apk: send msg like 5;del;45  (speed,state,servo_position)
this is my car code (tcp server):

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define M_ATRAS 4
#define M_ADELANTE 5
#define M_VELOCIDAD 6

Servo servo;  // Crea un Objeto servo  
SoftwareSerial ESP8266(3,2); //1)RX-> Azul, 2)TX->Amarillo

String mar;
int vel;
int rot;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Iniciando...");

  comandoESP("AT+RST"); // reset module
  comandoESP("AT+CWMODE=3"); // configure as access point
  //comandoESP("AT+CWSAP=\"ESP\",\"1234567890\",3,3"); //SSID,PASSWORD,CHANNEL,PASSWORD-ENCRYPATION(0=NO PASSWORD)                                               //0 is encryption type like 0 = Open, 2 =WPA_PSK, 3 = WPA2_PSK, 4 = WPA_WPA2_PSK
  comandoESP("AT+CWJAP=\"tfh\",\"fggrtfdfgdtg\"");
  comandoESP("AT+CIPMUX=1"); // configure for multiple connections
  comandoESP("AT+CIPSERVER=1,400"); // turn on server on port x

  Serial.println("Servidor TCP ON...");

  pinMode(M_VELOCIDAD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M_ATRAS,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M_ADELANTE,OUTPUT);
  velocidad(0);
  servo.attach(7);  // Selecionamos el pinde control para el servo  Rango: 0<->155
  Serial.println("Posicion delservo: "+String(servo.read())); 
}

void loop()
{ 
  if(ESP8266.available())
  {
    if(ESP8266.findUntil("+IPD,","."))
    {
      vel=ESP8266.readStringUntil(';').toInt();
      mar=ESP8266.readStringUntil(';');
      rot=ESP8266.readStringUntil(';').toInt();
      velocidad( vel);
      marcha(mar);
      rotacion(rot);
      Serial.println(String(vel)+"-"+mar+"-"+String(rot));
    }        
  }
}

void marcha(String tipo){
  if(tipo == "del")
  {
    //Serial.println("Adelante?");
    digitalWrite(M_ATRAS,LOW);
    digitalWrite(M_ADELANTE,HIGH);
  }
  else if(tipo == "tra")
  {
    //Serial.println("Atras?");
    digitalWrite(M_ATRAS,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(M_ADELANTE,LOW);
  }
}
void velocidad(int v){
  //Serial.println("Velocidad: "+String(v));
  analogWrite(M_VELOCIDAD, v); 
} 

void rotacion(int r){
  int rot =map(r,-10, 10, 125, 0); //mapeamos los valores que puede tener el acelerometro a los valores que puede tener el servo
  //Serial.println("Acelerometro: "+String(r)+" Servo: "+String(rot));
  servo.write(rot);
}
void comandoESP(String cmd)
{
  ESP8266.println(cmd);

  if(ESP8266.available())
    Serial.println(ESP8266.readStringUntil(14));

  delay(1000*3); //3seg
}
```

Comment: Possibly it is a baud rate issue. Chips can provide baud but with some error rate due to their clock freq. Try using alternate lower bauds.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own AT Commands, use a library and use Virtual Serial.

[WeeESP8266](https://github.com/itead/ITEADLIB_Arduino_WeeESP8266) is a nice library. See my [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2015/04/simple-twitter-sentiment-notification.html) on how to put all together.

Comment: hi, i try using that library in arduino uno,  but  dont found gertter methodlike getLocalIP, or getVersion,... and someime another functions give me error and i need restart arduino.